# Probabilidades com função pnorm R

Tags: r

Estatistica e Probabilidade não é minha area. Surgiu uma duvida, acho que estou fazendo certo mas o resultado esta estranho. Essa é a minha serie:

```
y=structure(c(-0.276926746036887, 5.1002303288006, -4.45902094037891, 
-3.65240790618631, -0.554369416754141, 0.554369416754141, -2.25772100857938, 
0.375468281204183, -2.05228159135609, 3.29532926592406, -1.32662877100271, 
0.988930229485896, 7.07229348341512, -1.28656226502041, 4.2549381884453, 
3.30389447729236, 7.00232043259232, 4.7748331221784, -0.27085058060754, 
2.30352233190845, -3.22100247146746, -4.8743614652375, 2.06839209389353, 
1.89690621078412, 3.19172094544754, 2.16583767731922, -0.756218240014694, 
0.19541235523014, 3.14867268321485, -0.144151053557329, 1.01160305514936, 
1.5230454220633, 1.03840992420788, 2.71968062765501, 0.861247787660713, 
6.23477534727392, 0.5745094967259, 1.93701233271648, -4.92253766463621, 
-2.73591768775421, 4.3088310528527, 0.851783504402864, 1.72544081552388, 
-0.246815828758246, 0.166106780480357, 2.17708551212288, 0.789826760142481, 
3.52664861321393, -6.1785670816505, 3.6211660479106, 2.78553748264525, 
0.89906385457475, 2.04066324333774, 3.76850202784195, -0.0156889406364658, 
5.78634965275749, 1.26423314049121, 1.78013275057423, 3.31172073861811, 
2.4038546444218, 4.66258664624009, -13.5843132751602, -0.403750718769838, 
-3.56233196110176, -1.81026841297745, -7.46631529569132, 1.42758499302842, 
-1.24995503682966, -2.24626121938432, -3.31120681505209, 2.99957221381565, 
2.30969024677898, -2.37907446465362, -1.88443844926011, -5.12583959903528, 
5.20685002435163, -3.97367473360913, 2.67851563087302, 0.235381859142514, 
2.80824193248285, 2.89610807313333, -1.9729824987724, -3.3615385580259, 
-2.10190280870005, -2.09136151458093, -3.87094266631358, -3.2751255099671, 
1.8850792597277, 1.02942443142527, 1.36158956227371, -2.59327811511363, 
0.491897726102963, -5.78257606259328, -5.87069602591836, -3.25452200548395, 
6.39760964001113, -0.247985247978266, -6.1760320126711, 0.423565923494829, 
2.17040312533964, 7.31569072572449, -0.0871727871011863, 1.621556300047, 
-0.504340241336876, -4.50860952107559, -4.4400301974362, 2.23109247118944, 
3.28749943941721, 0.344162253040281, 3.43025943921054, -0.226072675706557, 
7.21093155995787, 1.44163507753278, -7.28040722370891, 5.74286395911455, 
-2.60392371230649, 2.31880108190266, 0.508242311922885, -2.82704339382555, 
-3.94015554915489, -0.582767936456074, 2.46930245946095, 0.553845041192957, 
-2.26755057988116, -4.00552887824704, -6.38198320512942, -1.70521028736478, 
0.982781138056799, -3.69451268069177, 0.246585308476566, 0.55308591968849, 
-1.8746351610273, 2.84001033287316, 8.83299994192822, 1.49942937302144, 
1.43144209241926, 4.82628292850097, -4.02801052546, 0.267481044687123, 
-4.19615590666126, 0.543398882231305, -1.31021176393017, -5.53706210900828, 
4.21482279511858, 1.86102992601902, 1.12800218208342, -2.20317694783819, 
-2.99809865598509, -3.9927697470259, -0.862197910255613, -3.54699081750229, 
11.1743775531587, 12.9770616075187, 3.18619731487439, 0.0317784590121939, 
1.83499639512377, 4.40415488243423, -5.97321376720503, -3.93178975523039, 
0.57591946095546, 4.42156241654894, 0.537527630812085, -0.121844321824688, 
-0.61744241735453, 0.523729365789133, 0.200706255816196, 0.519958804533455, 
-1.54404705357017, 0.86950573958392, -0.0327307895505558, -1.58683494663899, 
-0.013607190665299, -2.37306791586077, 0.440301351691902, 0.344705879693602, 
-2.62103933785511, -3.61112663327796, 4.24778609707985, 0.0313351928111716, 
-0.952260731392018, -0.158275463946334, -2.18588813267492, 0.613340421034958, 
1.41402133928985, -0.250985009120286, -0.470304013118084, 2.95224973756179, 
-1.78771862889961, -0.0758449638961822, 3.24567999848993, -1.51097540057064, 
2.86670167933881, -1.4720908190912, 0.379216944245919, 1.39885736740112, 
-2.91513301487977, -0.218721729003968, -0.174077974918679, -0.358434494209331, 
-0.262627361006695, -3.91537200150442, -3.27447875910531, -1.78701946030079, 
6.70983840143415, -1.70370125158495, -0.983681568317685, 1.51971910738222, 
-0.98330489803079, -1.75605251878265, 1.58576167333393, 1.1341537292256, 
0.533282885011355, -4.06735941384394, -0.58755861516564, 2.74957162619566, 
0.622289734338011, -0.780114417335526, -1.87837155096527, 0.226072054152004, 
2.5368406372972, -2.34466303952749, 2.09320149165367, -2.48295466772607, 
-1.39236880883822, 1.54309735856075, 1.50481181337672, -0.864243789878039, 
1.0338958791585, 2.64716085607346, -0.702852086409766, 0.341588718140706, 
0.404527399709431, 1.60509437116675, -2.76525626967899, 0.749200216946883, 
-2.27946320594848, 0.19400561795847, 3.02847564751852, -1.3395241719926, 
-0.197225968421838, 2.51515239525749, -0.895573323697879, 2.29956699052384, 
3.87915217893021, -1.07749609076405, 0.977159881194761, 3.17346515886144, 
-1.85765670111033, 1.92585418625068, 2.05443904262965, -5.10898848846342, 
2.31349795923873, 1.23878810661255, 1.69870352568162, -0.814981856773006, 
0.919933007395513, 0.693588874876505, -1.23512568593857, -1.79467292197339, 
-1.23956764741749, 1.07546772749542, 1.93739237643256, -1.99990828004241, 
2.95188431410198, -0.0635606707981018, -0.852783793313855, -2.18690287354734, 
-0.410120764875582, -4.15224123307232, -2.46163901733218, 0.957897478032321, 
-1.43716915209405, 0.446453789583057, 0.494251639553211, -3.42523616802606, 
-2.17046135806602, 4.41921336813345, -0.335763862240462, -1.32083839660705, 
-2.42762992607925, -0.82634215069915, 2.69239819821484, 1.98972704914046, 
-5.23074389240228, -2.00100680366893, -1.53953028309399, -3.55446542103525, 
-2.06954910327771, -1.95713201456629, 0.946560098399563, 3.63170421214811, 
-3.24970892660951, 1.11918342199998, -0.314074601207448, 0.840158487264464, 
-0.326895061687471, -1.40089184945676, -3.89052244917483, -0.454972014583788, 
1.63056386213887, -2.09531475147559, 1.89341455741064, -1.23150989131111, 
4.77196538893804, 1.66515332371626, 1.89683518961253, -2.35330107339518, 
1.76926250072161, 0.040693200374009, 2.10220842655976, 0.771271929555351, 
-3.61206762105296, 1.58934142527959, 0.836620342328287, -4.64587274736759, 
-2.77107914576235, 1.29533561334032, -1.04463858207546, -1.79675468861598, 
1.63218869418859, -1.94848787942505, -3.14046238852407, 0.544018624569886, 
-0.127392297256357, -0.00980613276329034, -0.365473065125499, 
-1.58733491562901, 1.01879263874898, -1.33529297306464, -1.48767751576085, 
0.980797357366159, -1.10305672543544, -1.88529499316701, 1.01498530290741, 
3.58364274627491, -0.262274385874206, 0.157049880696913, 0.0456770639576165, 
0.039702233772132, 0.271537324819782, -0.567698382468329, 0.502358961664562, 
8.51230456682989, 2.14508593839724, 9.65767019796469, 5.18629487924251, 
4.8662255853938, 1.41817523625373, 0.955339050012599, -0.167170359769503, 
-3.43010456552938, -8.79805101759148, -1.79194933762561, -1.57363442942458, 
2.41735538894081, 1.91796218652891, -2.92469310269456), .Tsp = c(1980.08333333333, 
2009.75, 12), class = "ts")
```

Eu quero calcular probabilidades usando a função de distribuição Normal Acumulada:

Prob(X< quartil.25)

```
pnorm(quantile(y,.25), mean = mean(y), sd = sd(y), lower.tail=TRUE)
```

Prob(X> quartil 75)

```
1-pnorm(quantile(y,.75), mean = mean(y), sd = sd(y), lower.tail=TRUE)
```

Essas probabilidade não deveriam ser iguais pois se trata de uma distribuição normal?

Estou fazendo corretamente?

Answer (score 3):

Sim, tu está fazendo tudo corretamente.

Se formos nos ater à teoria, sim, estes dois resultados deveriam ser iguais. Se os teus dados vem de uma distribuição normal, estes dois valores devem ser iguais.

(de maneira mais geral, este resultado vale pra qualquer distribuição de probabilidade que seja simétrica em relação à média)

Eu não sei a origem dos teus dados. Imagino que sejam simulados ou provenientes de alguma série temporal real. Neste caso, não temos garantia nenhuma de que estes dois valores sejam iguais. O máximo que podemos obter são aproximações para os valores destes quartis. No teu caso, os valores foram

```
> pnorm(quantile(y,.25), mean = mean(y), sd = sd(y), lower.tail=TRUE)
      25% 
0.2668025 
> 1-pnorm(quantile(y,.75), mean = mean(y), sd = sd(y), lower.tail=TRUE)
      75% 
0.2836341
```

que são aproximações bastante razoáveis para estes quartis.

Veja outro exemplo. Suponha que eu queira gerar uma amostra aleatória de tamanho 100, com média 0 e desvio padrão 1, de uma variável aleatória com distribuição normal. Vou chamar isto de `x` e estimar a sua média:

```
x <- rnorm(100, mean=0, sd=1)
mean(x)
[1] 0.0005606774
```

Por mais que tu repita este experimento, a estimativa da média nunca vai ser zero. É muito pouco provável que isto ocorra. Entretanto, a aproximação que obtemos é razoavelmente boa. Aliás, é tão boa que se eu realizar um testes de hipóteses para verificar se esta média é, de fato, zero, obtenho

```
t.test(x)

    One Sample t-test

data:  x
t = 0.00624, df = 99, p-value = 0.995
alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.1777242  0.1788455
sample estimates:
   mean of x 
0.0005606774
```

Note que o p-valor foi super alta, indicando que não podemos rejeitar H_0. Ou seja, a média desta amostra é, de fato, zero.

Em resumo, não te preocupa. A tua lógica está correta e esta pequena diferença é esperada. Devido às flutuações na geração deste números, seja via simulação ou à natureza real deles, eles não são perfeitamente simétricos em relação à média. Mas esta característica é esperada.

Comment: muito obrigada! Acontece que estou encontrando diferença na primeira casa decimal tbm. Mas estou aliaviada por saber que esta certo e de ter entendido sua explicação. Tenho uma probabilidade que esta dando 0.2 e outra 0.3. Enfim, mas foi entendido. Obrigada, novamente.